# Converting multiple files from tab-delimited to comma-delimited CSV

Tags: text-processing, csv

How can I change tab-delimited `.txt` files into CSV files without harming the format?

I only managed to change the type from `.txt` to `.csv` but all data that was separated by tab, was placed in the same Excel cell.

So what I'm asking here is:

1. how to change tab to a comma for many files?
2. how to then change the files from `.txt` to `.csv`?

Comment: Is there exactly one tab between the columns or could there be more that need to replaced by a single comma?

Comment: it's just one tab

Comment: realizing that you're asking on Unix & Linux, I removed the "cmd" solution request along with the other edits.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
perl -MText::CSV -F'\t' -i.orig -lape '
  BEGIN{$c = Text::CSV->new({binary=>1, eol=>""})}
  $_ = $c->string if $c->combine(@F)' ./*.txt
```

To convert to *proper* CSV (see `perldoc Text::CSV` in case you need to adjust the format of the CSV). If all you need is to convert tabs to commas, it's  just a matter of `tr '\t' , < file.txt > file.csv`.

Comment: yes. CSV has a few nasty edge cases, so using a well-tested CSV library is crucial.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

Assuming an input file like

```
a       10,000  e       u
a       o       e       u
a       o       "hello  world"  u
a       o       e       u
```

where all fields are tab-delimited and where there's also a tab in-between the `hello` and `world` (even though the two words belong to the same field as indicated by the quoting).

```
$ csvformat -t file.txt
a,"10,000",e,u
a,o,e,u
a,o,hello       world,u
a,o,e,u
```

The `-t` option to `csvformat` tells the utility that the input is tab-delimited.

Notice that the `10,000` is properly quoted and that the quotes around `hello<tab>world` were removed as it's now unambiguous.

To force quoting of all fields:

```
$ csvformat -t -U 1 file.txt
"a","10,000","e","u"
"a","o","e","u"
"a","o","hello  world","u"
"a","o","e","u"
```

If the input is using another quote character, as in

```
$ cat file.txt
a       10,000  e       u
a       o       e       u
a       o       'quote: "hello  world"' u
a       o       e       u
```

then do this:

```
$ csvformat -t -q "'" file.txt
a,"10,000",e,u
a,o,e,u
a,o,"quote: ""hello     world""",u
a,o,e,u
```

We specify that the single quote is used in the input data with `-q "'"`.

---

To run this on several files, converting each from tab-delimited to CSV, assuming we want to process all `.txt` files in the *current* directory:

```
for name in ./*.txt; do
    csvformat -t "$name" >"${name%.txt}.csv"
done
```

The `${name%.txt}.csv` bit removes the extension `.txt` from the filename and adds a `.csv` extension instead.  This can also be written as

```
for name in ./*.txt; do
    csvformat -t "$name" >"./$( basename "$name" .txt ).csv"
done
```

You will then have a set of (untouched original) `.txt` files together with their corresponding `.csv` files.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the command below

```
sed 's/\t/,/g' yourtab.txt > updatefile.csv
```

Comment: For proper CSV handling, you would have to double quote any data field that contains a comma already. ... and escape any existing quotes obviously.

Comment: Thanks but can I use it on more than one file at a time?

Comment: Note that `\t` for tab is a GNU extension

Comment: I managed to change all files but into one file using this:

Comment: sed 's/\t/,/g' *.txt > 1.csv

How can I keep the files separated?

Comment: and what would be the parallel command for cmd?